# Consistency of Posterior

Tags: bayesian, posterior, consistency

I have a conceptual question regarding the definition of the consistency of a Bayesian posterior.

I found this definition on the web:

Given the i.i.d. data $x_1,...,x_n$ and the model $f_\theta(x)$, the posterior distribution $\Pi_n$ is *consistent* if $$\forall \epsilon >0 \lim_{n\to\infty}\Pi_n(|\theta - \theta_0|>\epsilon)\to 0,$$ where $\theta_0$ is the true parameter.

Is this the right definition? I don't understand how the "true" parameter $\theta_0$ can be used as a constant in a Bayesian setting, because I read that the distinction to the frequentist approach is, that in a Bayesian setting the parameter is conceptualized as a random variable and not a constant.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: If your expression missing a $\mathbb P$?

Comment: In the frequentist consistency definition there is a $\mathbb{P}$ in place of the posterior distribution $\Pi_n$, but here the $\Pi_n$ is the probability measure, (at least that's how I interpreted it).

Comment: I was reading too fast and thought you had a product $\prod_n$.  You might want to look at https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~ghoshal/papers/bhurev.pdf which has a definition of consistency at the top of page 2 (it uses $\mu_n$ as the posterior measure) and talks about other related issues. In a Bayesian setting, the posterior distribution is a description of the distribution of belief about the unknown parameter, informed by the observations;  this distribution behaves like the distribution of a random variable

Comment: Thank you! In the definition mentioned there, it also sounds like they view $\theta_0$ as a constant. Do I then understand it right that Bayesians in fact do believe that ''out there'' exists a fixed true parameter point? 
They just look for it in a different way than Frequentists?